# Change dataframe columns if column name exist in other dataframe, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a main data frame (DF) with below columns & data

```
C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   QC
254 95  0   34543   43  32  4   4   4   4   Q23
255 59  1   43  tre     r5  54  567 564 Q23
256 50  7   65      76557   65  65  5   5   Q23
```

And, mapping dataframe(MDF) with below columns

```
QC  Res1    Res2    Res3    Res4    Res5    Res6    Res7    Res8    Res9    Res10
Q23 US  CH  JP  CE  OV  NON DK  TOT N   KK
Q24 US  ZZ  JP  ME  KP  NON DK  TOT E   LK
```

Here, column QC in both dataframe is for mapping.

I want to replace DF columns by mapping with MDF where MDF['QC']=DF[Q23]

Order is the same in both the dataframe. I have total 500 dataframe, I want to update all dataframe columns with new columns that present in another dataframe.

Final Expected dataframe: DF

```
US      CH  JP  CE  OV  NON DK  TOT N   KK  QC
254 95  0   34543   43  32  4   4   4   4   Q23
255 59  1   43  tre     r5  54  567 564 Q23
256 50  7   65      76557   65  65  5   5   Q23
```

This is really challenging one.

Comment: Do you have only one dataframe or list of dataframes?

Comment: @Bharath shetty, total 343 dataset.

Comment: Is QC value same across column per dataset

Comment: Yes, QC values are same across in same data set, but different in each dataset

Comment: I updated my answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.append by selecting the row of that contains 'QC's value i.e

If you have dataframes like

```
print(df1)
     C   D  E      F    G        H   I   J    K    L   QC
0  254  95  0  34543   43     32.0   4   4    4    4  Q23
1  255  59  1     43  tre      NaN  r5  54  567  564  Q23
2  256  50  7     65  NaN  76557.0  65  65    5    5  Q23
```

```
print(df2)
   C   D  E      F    G        H   I   J    K    L   QC
0  254  95  0  34543   43     32.0   4   4    4    4  Q24
1  255  59  1     43  tre      NaN  r5  54  567  564  Q24
2  256  50  7     65  NaN  76557.0  65  65    5    5  Q24
```

Then a for loop to assign the columns would help you i.e

```
for i in [df1,df2]:
    q = i['QC'].unique()[0]
    i.columns = np.append(mdf[mdf['QC'] == q].values[0][1:],['QC'])

print([df1,df2]
```

```
[    US  CH  JP     CE   OV      NON  DK  TOT    N   KK   QC
0  254  95   0  34543   43     32.0   4    4    4    4  Q23
1  255  59   1     43  tre      NaN  r5   54  567  564  Q23
2  256  50   7     65  NaN  76557.0  65   65    5    5  Q23,     
     US  ZZ  JP     ME   KP      NON  DK  TOT    E   LK   QC
0  254  95   0  34543   43     32.0   4    4    4    4  Q24
1  255  59   1     43  tre      NaN  r5   54  567  564  Q24
2  256  50   7     65  NaN  76557.0  65   65    5    5  Q24]
```